How did they get the horse, Badger, in the 1978 ep. “Beauty of the Beast” in All Creatures Great and Small to shake and tremble so severely?
I just recently signed up for BritBox streaming service and started enjoying the old 1970s version of “All Creatures Great and Small." Well, enjoying it until just now: while watching the series 2 episode “Beauty of the Beast," I couldn’t help but notice the horse playing Badger trembling and shuddering on the ground as if it was truly in great amounts of pain and distress.
How did they accomplish that? Was this actually a case of animal cruelty to a creature they planned to put down anyway?

It's vanishingly unlikely. Don't forget that this is a TV show, so they probably just trained the horse to lie down and wiggled it around to make it look like it was having a fit.

"None of us ever did anything that could harm an animal," explained Timothy in another interview. "The injections were all faked and arms up a cow's bum is not difficult to do—and the cows don't mind too much... in fact, some cows quite like it! Jack Watkinson wouldn't tolerate anything that he deemed as unethical. The directors at one point sent out a note about how animals should be treated in the furtherance of entertainment, but it was always left to the attending vet's discretion. If it had gone against any of his ethical code, Jack would have refused us to do it."
